# Relaciones con Laravel y jquery

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Buenas tardes estoy creando una datatable con jquery y mi controlador de laravel, si hay una relación simple no tengo problemas, en la consulta hago un `whith` y puedo acceder a ella dede la respuesta de ajax, el problema me es, cuando una relación depende de varias tablas.

**Mi tabla clientes**

| id | name | apellidos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nombre1 | Apellidos2 |
| 2 | Nombre2 | Apellidos2 |

**Mi tabla ubicacions**

| id | cliente_id | municipio | provincia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 865 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 866 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 870 | 5 |

**Mi tabla provincias**

| id | provincia |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Valencia |
| 4 | Barcelona |
| 5 | Madrid |

**Mi tabla municipios**

| id | municipio |
| --- | --- |
| 856 | Paterna |
| 866 | Sitges |
| 870 | Mostoles |

Bien luego tengo mis relaciones:

**Mi modelo cliente**

```
protected $connection = 'mysql';
protected $table = 'clientes';
protected $primaryKey='id';

public function ubicaciones()
 {
   return $this->hasOne(Ubicacion::class, 'cliente_id');
 }
```

**Mi modelo Ubicacion**

```
protected $table = 'ubicacions';
protected $primaryKey='id';


public function Provincia(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Provincia::class, 'ciudad', 'id');
}

public function Municipio(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Municipio::class, 'poblacion', 'id');
}
```

Estas relaciones las gasto en php sin ningún problema, una vez que accedo a la primero puedo acceder a la segunda.

La idea es que en mi controlador hago lo siguiente:

```
$clientes = Cliente::with('mensajesDeUsuarios', 'ubicaciones').....
```

Pero ubicaciones solo me trae las id de Provincia y municipio, hay forma de traer el nombre??

Comment: Si quieres acceder a las otras relaciones tienes que hacer los sigueinte, $clientes = Cliente::with('mensajesDeUsuarios', 'ubicaciones.Provincia','ubicaciones.Municipio'); de este forma estos datos iran en tu consulta

Comment: Hola @HeynerMartinez si que me llegan los datos a mi consulta, eso es estupendo. Pero no consigo imprimirlo `data.ubicaciones.municipio.municipio` pero no existe

Comment: Vale modifico, si lo lee. Pero claro puede darse el caso que uno este vacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Esta respuesta se basa en el contexto actual de la pregunta, sin embargo conviene analizar los cuestionamientos expuestos en la parte final.

1. De acuerdo con las tablas expuestas, la relación entre `clientes`, `municipios` y `provincias` se puede *entender* como: *many to many* por la existencia de la tabla intermedia `ubicacions`
2. La tabla intermedia `ubicacions` no necesita un modelo vinculado
3. Ahora bien considero que si `cliente` puede tener múltiples ubicaciones como comentaste, entonces el método a emplear debe ser: [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)de la siguiente forma:

Modelo User:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function municipios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Municipio::class, 'ubicacions', 'cliente_id', 'municipio');
    }

    public function provincias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Provincia::class, 'ubicacions', 'cliente_id', 'provincia');
    }
}
```

Y obviamente definir las relaciones equivalentes en los modelos:

- Municipio
- Provincia

Para que finalmente la consulta quede de esta forma:

```
Cliente::with(['municipios', 'provincias'])->get();
```

Que te dará como resultado una colección de todos los clientes y dentro de cada objeto 2 colecciones, una con todos los municipios relacionados y otra con las provincias vinculadas.

Finalmente te dejo los siguientes cuestionamientos **para que analices**:

- ¿Cliente solo tiene un municipio asociado?, de ser así ¿entonces por que registrarlo en una tabla externa?, cuando de hecho podría quedar como atributo de cada cliente.
- No veo relación entre provincia y municipio, ¿no se vinculan?, ¿una provincia no se compone de varios municipios?, de ser así entonces ahí queda pendiente una relación no solo a nivel de Eloquent sino de SQL pues los estás tratando como elementos aislados.

Si lo anterior se cumple, entonces **realizando las adecuaciones necesarias tanto en SQL como en Eloquent** generaría una consulta mas simple de este modo:

```
Cliente::with('municipio.provincia')->get();
```

Recomiendo revises a detalle lo comentado.

Comment: Funciona perfecto Beta!!! Gracias como siempre!